# После отправки формы страница все время обновляется

Tags: javascript, php, форма

Есть форма для заказа обратного звонка. Все данные приходят, но страница успешной отправки перенаправляет на главную. После отправки пользователь должен оставаться на странице отправки. Все мои попытки сделать это не сработали.

Форма

```
<form action="/wp-content/themes/cluster/send.php" metohod="POST" class="form">
    <div class="container _anim-items _active">
      <h2 class="form__title">С радостью ответим <br> на любые вопросы</h2>
      <p class="form__subtitle">Заполните нашу форму обратного вызова и наши специалисты свяжутся с вами в течение 5 минут</p>
      <div class="form__inner">
        <div class="form__left">
        <input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
          <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя">
          <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="+7(000)000-00-00">
          <button class="form__btn" type="submit">
            <span>Отправить</span>
          </button>
          <p class="agreement">Нажимая на кнопку, вы даете <a href="#">согласие на обработку своих персональных данных</a> и получение сообщений </p>
        </div>
        <div class="form__img-wrapper">
          <picture><source srcset="/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/board1.webp" type="image/webp"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/board1.png" class="form__img" alt="картинка"></picture>
          <picture><source srcset="/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/board.webp" type="image/webp"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/board.png" class="form__img_tablet" alt="картинка"></picture>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

send.php

```
<?php
/* Здесь проверяется существование переменных */
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$phone = $_POST['name'];}
if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {$name = $_POST['phone'];}


/* Сюда впишите свою эл. почту */
$myaddres  = "rixicij851@corylan.com"; // кому отправляем
$link = $_REQUEST['url'];
// $title = print($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

 
/* А здесь прописывается текст сообщения, \n - перенос строки */
$mes = "Тема: Заказ обратного звонка!\nТелефон: $phone\nИмя: $name\nСсылка: $link\n";

 
/* А эта функция как раз занимается отправкой письма на указанный вами email */
$sub='Заказ'; //сабж
$email='Заказ обратного звонка'; // от кого
$send = mail ($myaddres,$sub,$mes,"Content-type:text/plain; charset = utf-8\r\nFrom:$email");
 
ini_set('short_open_tag', 'On');
header('Refresh: 3; URL=');
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/clusterfloor/css/style.min.css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3"; url="">
<title>Спасибо! Мы свяжемся с вами!</title>
<meta name="generator">
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout('location.replace("/index")', 3000);
/*Изменить текущий адрес страницы через 3 секунды (3000 миллисекунд)*/
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="form-sent sent" data-target="form-popup">
    <p class="form-sent__title">Спасибо, заявка отправлена!</p>
    <picture><source srcset="/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/form-sent.svg" type="image/webp"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/form-sent.svg" alt="картинка"></picture>
    <a href="/index" class="form-sent__link">Вернуться на главную</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Я пробовал изменить время setTimeout, удалить скрипт вообще но от этого страница успешной отправки начинает без конца обновляться и при каждом обновлении идет отправка письма.

Пробовал так же что то сделать с этой конструкцией, тоже не помогло.

```
ini_set('short_open_tag', 'On');
header('Refresh: 3; URL=');
```

**UPD:** вот что заметил в консоли:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `metohod="POST"` - что это? И тут косяк: `$phone = $_POST['name']`. И дальше. И где вобще форма расположена? В каком файле? И зачем вы делаете `location.replace("/index")`?

Comment: Опечатку я исправил. А что не так с этим `$phone = $_POST['name']`? Форма находится в отдельном файле в папке template-parts (вордпресс) и вставляется на главную страницу (index.php) при загрузке. Я нашел готовый код и там был `location.replace("/index")`. Я пробовал его убрать, но от этого страница после отправки постоянно перезагружается и отправляет письма бесконечно

Comment: `$phone = $_POST['name']` - так в переменную `$phone` будут грузиться данные из поля `name`. А перенаправление нужно вообще убрать.

Comment: Да, косяк, хотя проверял вроде. Но суть не в этом. Если убрать скрипт или как то его изменить то страница отправки все время обновляется и отправляет письма без остановки. Вот видео этого процесса https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PgR1V7bU76MLPxo94IOkg-c89OjEfW45/view?usp=sharing

Comment: А если удалить строки `header('Refresh: 3; URL=');` и `setTimeout('location.replace("/index")', 3000);`?

Comment: Результат тот же. И это странно

Answer (score 0):

Нашел причину! Погуглил limited quirks mode и вот что нашел:

> Необходимо удостовериться, что тег DOCTYPE находится в самом начале
> HTML документа. Если на странице будет что-либо до тега DOCTYPE,
> например, комментарий или декларирование XML, то браузеры Internet
> Explorer 9 и выше будут переведены в режим совместимости.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode